# xsl obtain child node variables

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm a newbee to using xsl
I have a section of xml;

```
<log logtime="06 Nov 14 14:58:50:067">
    <severity>Severe</severity>
    <text>ASDF.</text>
</log>
```

I am having trouble looping round the log child nodes into variables as I would like to render this as;

```
Date                      Sev     Text<br>
06 Nov 14 14:58:50:067    Severe  ASDF.
```

Thanks in advance and any help appreciated

Comment: Th question is not quite clear: are there different formats of `log`? It seems like you want to hard-code the headings, so there's nothing to loop over here - just pick the the three data values. -- The format of the output is also not clear.

Comment: Where is the XSLT that you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

The section where you process this log should start with something like

```
<xsl: template match="log">
```

Within that template you can set up a table to render the 3 columns and their headers.
To read the values:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@logtime">
<xsl:value-of select="./severity">
```